# Using "use strict" but still get the warning

Tags: javascript, jslint

HI guys Im  trying to get use to using JSLint and I am getting the 'use strict' warning and after adding it to the function I still get the missing 'use strict' statement

```
    fs.readFile('file', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) { "use strict"; throw err; }
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
  });
```

i was curious to what i am  doing wrong?

Comment: move `"use strict"` in the 1st line of your inner function (before the if statement), this should solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% positive on this, but I've only ever used `'use strict';` at the top of a given .js file, not embedded in the code.  And I've not gotten the warning after doing so. Perhaps that's where jslint looks for it.

Further, looking at the documentation for it, `use strict` should be scoped either to the whole script, (top of the file) or to a given function (top of the function, right after the opening brace).  So regardless of jslint's capabilities, that should be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The location of the [`"use strict"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) directive is the issue.

**Usages:**

```
// Top of script file
"use strict";
/* ... code ... */
```

Or:

```
function b() {
  "use strict";
  /* ... code ... */
}
```

You're using it inside the block of an `if` branch.

Comment: It's not just common, it's the rules! `"use strict";` has to be the first statement of a file, or the first statement of a function to take effect.

Comment: @hobbs is correct - otherwise it's simply ignored by the web browser and functions execute differently. Please fix this answer.

Comment: Sorry -- already deleted comment; missed where you said "first statement of a function". Trying to see what's wrong with alexfreiria's answer that @BenjaminGruenbaum dislikes.  alexfreiria's edit was just to add the `use strict` link to MDN; I don't see anything wrong with the answer.

Comment: @ruffin alex already edited the answer after Benjamin's comment. :)

Comment: Right, but see prev comment. [All he changed](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27252940/revisions) was adding the link here: *The location of the [`"use strict"`][1] directive is the issue.* The code's the same. ?